# Gateway laptop no longer recognizes wireless hardware after hard reboot

Tags: 11.10, wireless, hardware, laptop

I had wireless working with no problems. Laptop froze and required hard reboot.

Since then the laptop does not recognize internal wireless hardware.

Wireless network still working with other devices. Laptop can access network with wired ethernet connection.

I suspect a hardware failure given the sequence of events. I miss the 'administration' menu available in previous releases that allowed me to see what hardware was installed, working or has problem.

Any and all suggestions appreciated. Thank you in advance for you assistance.

Comment: Have also lost sound now. Don't know how or if problems are connected.